# Creating Test data for ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb

Hi I would like to insert random test data into an edge collection called Transaction with the fields _id, Amount and TransferType with random data. I have written the following code below, but it is showing a syntax error.

```
FOR i IN 1..30000
  INSERT {
    _id: CONCAT('Transaction/', i),
    Amount:RAND(),
    Time:Rand(DATE_TIMESTAMP),
    i > 1000 || u.Type_of_Transfer == "NEFT" ? u.Type_of_Transfer == "IMPS"
  } INTO Transaction OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues:

- When you are creating a new document you can either not specify the `_key` key and Arango will create one for you, or you specify one as a string to be used. `_id` as a key will be ignored.
- `RAND()` produces a random number between 0 and 1, so it needs to be multiplied in order to make it into the range you want you might need to round it, if you need integer values.
- `DATE_TIMESTAMP` is a function and you have given it as a parameter to the RAND() function which needs no parameter. But because it generates a numerical timestamp (milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC), actually it's not needed. The only thing you need is the random number generation shifted to a range that makes sense (ie: not in the 1970s)
- The `i > 1000 ...` line is something I could only guess what it wanted to be. Here the key for the JSON object is missing. You are referencing a `u` variable that is not defined anywhere. I see the first two parts of a ternary operator expression (`cond ? true_value : false_value`) but the `:` is missing. My best guess is that you wanted to create a `Type_of_transfer` key with value of "NEFT" when `i>1000` and "IMPS" when `i<=1000`

So, I rewrote your AQL and tested it

```
FOR i IN 1..30000
  INSERT {
    _key: TO_STRING(i),
    Amount: RAND()*1000,
    Time: ROUND(RAND()*100000000+1603031645000),
    Type_of_Transfer: i > 1000 ? "NEFT" :  "IMPS"
  } INTO Transaction OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }
```